# Visual Studio code run as administrator won't run code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Hoping you can help me out here. When running VS code as administrator, VS code won't let me run any code in the terminal at all. Even the simplest code does not work.

When run normally, i have no trouble whatsoever, except for when i use functions which requires administrative privileges. This is where the issue arises.

This is the message i get when trying to run my python scripts in VS Studio code in administrator mode.

```
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Hope you guys can help me out, it's annoying.

VS Studio code: Newest Version. 
OS: Win 8.1
Python: 3.7.1